# Google App Script - Naming Folder After Client Upon Form Submission

Tags: google-chrome, google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-forms

I need help creating a script that will create a folder named after a client. This folder will be created upon form submission, using the answers from the form in the title. Additionally, after the folder is created, a similarly named document needs to be created inside of it. Currently, I have the document done. The document will generate and be named using information from the form's answers, but because its folder doesn't exist yet, I cannot script it to end up in its final destination.

Essentially what I need is this:

- Submit form entry for Jane Doe.
- Folder for Jane Doe is created.
- Document for Jane Doe is created and placed into folder.

---

```
var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(parentFolderId);
var newFolder = parentFolder.createFolder("firstname");
var templatefile = DriveApp.getFileById("1Y8OVDSlUPva6iGygjttBCsQqhaSQYwplrPhPP_-BJ44");
var templateResponneFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("16Tg8yB3B7qA_xdA9azu5JuuGDLDzlXfQ");
var copy = templatefile.makeCopy(organization + '-' + lastname+', '+ firstname + '-' + role + '-' + date,templateResponneFolder);
var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
```

---

This is the crux of what I am dealing with currently. The first two lines are the "new" script that I was toying around with within apps script. The way I understand it, this script will create a new folder simply titled "firstname" within a hitherto undefined parentfolder. Below that is the old script that would find the document template and then copy it.

P.S. can someone explain to me what the

- `var templateResponneFolder` and
- `var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());` do?

I don't know if you can tell, but I am very new to coding.

Full code:

```
function AutoFillGoogleDocFromForm(e) {
  var timestamp = e.values [0];
  var firstname = e.values [1];
  var lastname = e.values [2];
  var typeofa = e.values [3];
  var role = e.values [4];
  var organization = e.values [5];
  var date = e.values [6];
  var honorific = e.values [7];
  var pronouns1 = e.values [8];
  var pronouns2 = e.values [9];
  var intro = e.values [10];
  var intrv = e.values [11];
  var typeup = e.values [12];
  var test1 = e.values [13];
  var test1r = e.values [14];
  var test2 = e.values [15];
  var test2r = e.values [16];
  var test3 = e.values [17];
  var test3r = e.values [18];
  var test4 = e.values [19];
  var test4r = e.values [20];
  var test5 = e.values [21];
  var test5r = e.values [22];
  var test6 = e.values [23];
  var test6r = e.values [24];
  var test7 = e.values [25];
  var test7r = e.values [26];
  var test8 = e.values [27];
  var test8r = e.values [28];
  var test9 = e.values [29];
  var test9r = e.values [30];

  var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1k2rUCXQaVLaKeBUsoOUjxR_Ha29u8c_K");
  var newFolder = parentFolder.createFolder("My New Folder Name");

  var templatefile = DriveApp.getFileById("1Y8OVDSlUPva6iGygjttBCsQqhaSQYwplrPhPP_-BJ44");
  var templateResponneFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("16Tg8yB3B7qA_xdA9azu5JuuGDLDzlXfQ");

  var copy = templatefile.makeCopy(organization + '-' + lastname+', '+ firstname + '-' + role + '-' + date,templateResponneFolder);
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());

  var body = doc.getBody();

  body.replaceText ("{{TypeUp}}", typeup);
  body.replaceText ("{{Intro}}", intro);
  body.replaceText ("{{Intrv}}", intrv);
  body.replaceText ("{{Test1}}", test1);
  body.replaceText ("{{Test1r}}", test1r);
  body.replaceText ("{{Test2}}", test2);
  body.replaceText ("{{Test2r}}", test2r);
  body.replaceText ("{{Test3}}", test3);
  body.replaceText ("{{Test3r}}", test3r);
  body.replaceText ("{{Test4}}", test4);
  body.replaceText ("{{Test4r}}", test4r);
  body.replaceText ("{{Test5}}", test5);
  body.replaceText ("{{Test5r}}", test5r);
  body.replaceText ("{{Test6}}", test6);
  body.replaceText ("{{Test6r}}", test6r);
  body.replaceText ("{{Test7}}", test7);
  body.replaceText ("{{Test7r}}", test7r);
  body.replaceText ("{{Test8}}", test8);
  body.replaceText ("{{Test8r}}", test8r);

  body.replaceText ("{{FirstName}}", firstname);
  body.replaceText ("{{LastName}}", lastname);
  body.replaceText ("{{TypeofA}}", typeofa);
  body.replaceText ("{{Role}}", role);
  body.replaceText ("{{Organization}}", organization);
  body.replaceText ("{{Date}}", date);
  body.replaceText ("{{Honorific}}", honorific);
  body.replaceText ("{{pronoun1}}", pronouns1);
  body.replaceText ("{{pronoun2}}", pronouns2);


  doc.saveAndClose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the OP code has been adapted from another scenario. It includes some lines of code that have not been updated for the OP's scenario or that are unnecessary/redundant.

The following are the adjusted lines of code.
The OP must update these lines for their own Folder and File IDs

---

```
  var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1MhfwcdaTTUs6IQoNarrHib0gmCeXLOeh");
  var newFolder = parentFolder.createFolder(firstname);
  var templatefile = DriveApp.getFileById("1POT6tWtwa_aiwFI1B7uVO5DFA_OxH174CaVagRr5GW0");
  var copy = templatefile.makeCopy(organization + '-' + lastname+', '+ firstname + '-' + role + '-' + date,newFolder);
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
```

---

- `var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1MhfwcdaTTUs6IQoNarrHib0gmCeXLOeh");`

  - this identifies the folder which is the parent of the folders to be created by the script.
- `var newFolder = parentFolder.createFolder(firstname);`

  - `firstname` is one of the form responses.
  - this line creates a new folder for each form submission.
- `var templatefile = DriveApp.getFileById("1POT6tWtwa_aiwFI1B7uVO5DFA_OxH174CaVagRr5GW0");`

  - this is a Google Doc template that is used to merge with fields from the Form submissions.
  - it is identified by its Drive File id
- `var copy = templatefile.makeCopy(organization + '-' + lastname+', '+ firstname + '-' + role + '-' + date,newFolder);`

  - the Google Doc template is always copied before any merge. This line of code creates a copy of the "master", names it with variables from the form submission, and saves the new merge file to the `newFolder`.
  - Note that the destination folder, `newFolder`, has been substituted for `templateResponneFolder`
- `var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());`
- Having created the copy of the merge document, this line opens that file and the remainder of the script completes the merge and saves the merged file.

---

The OP asks the purpose of:

- `var templateResponneFolder`

  - No purpose whatsoever. This is a line that is redundant in the OP scenario.